# how to install the older version of android studio 2.1.2 in ubuntu

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
how to install the older version of android studio 2.1.2 in ubuntu ?
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you want to install a specific Android Studio version, you already have the **tar.gz** installation file. with that lets move on.

EDIT: To get older versions of Android Studio, check [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)

1. Install JDK on your PC

   ```
   sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
   ```
2. Extract the zipped **tar.gz** file to your preferred location.
3. open the `android-studio/bin` directory in your terminal and run the command:

   ```
   ./studio.sh
   ```

That would execute Android Studio, now the app is up and running.

---

A simpler process if you do not necessarily need an older version would be:

1. running this command on your terminal:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install android-studio
   ```

This would automatically download Android Studio and Install it from the Ubuntu App Store.

Comment: whether this will work  sudo apt-get install android-studio 2.1.2 ?

Comment: where i will get all the older version of android studio on  ubuntu ?

Comment: This  command sudo apt-get install android-studio will  latest version of android

Comment: Yes, the command would install the latest version of Android studio.

Comment: To get older versions of Android Studio, check https://developer.android.com/studio/archive